# How to interpret Hubble velocity ODE?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, space-expansion

Simple question. Hubble's law is

$v = \dfrac{dr}{dt} = H_0r$ .

The claim is that, if all galaxies are moving apart from one another, then at earlier times they were closer, and at some finite time in the past, they converge (infinite density, big bang).

But if we integrate Hubble's law, we find

$r(t) \propto e^{H_0t}$ .

But here, $r\rightarrow 0$ only in the event that $t\rightarrow -\infty$. If we set $t = t_0 = H_0^{-1}$, then we just end up with $r(t_0) \propto e$. Which does not seem consistent with sandard Big Bang theory.

This is actually an old argument used in Steady State theories, but it was presented and then never resolved in my cosmology text (Ryden). How do we reconcile this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@caverac is right. Note that his a's are the scale factor of the cosmological solution, the Friedman Lamaitre Robertson Walker solution. a is the quantity that depends on time, i.e., a = a(t), and it is this quantity that grows as the universe expands. D = a(t)r  is the proper distance (say between two far enough galaxies), and is what is measured cosmologically to be expanding. The Hubble velocity is its derivative with time. r is just a radial coordinate, but it has a metric tensor factor that is a(t).

The linearity of v (recession velocity) with D (proper distance) is good as long as H doesn't change much. That's true for us out to about a redshift of 1/2-1, and then it curves for higher redshifts. Hubble only saw the linear region. The wiki article referenced shows the graphic for v vs D for different cases.

See Wikipedia at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble%27s_law for the Hubble law and the equations from the FLRW solution.

And the only time you really have the exponential solution you found is when the universe is dark energy dominated. This is called a deSitter universe. Dark energy has a constant H, as you can see from caverac's equation when the a's have grown enough that the first and second term are negligible.

The universe is going towards being dark energy dominated, as you can see in that equation, as a increases. In some number of of billions of years, the universe expansion will be mainly exponential, with the Hubble time the e-doubling time.

Meanwhile, the equations from caverac are the ones to use, with actually the (normal, not dark) radiation at this time pretty irrelevant. At different times in the universe history different factors were the main contributors, and early mainly radiation, then malty matter, now a combination of about 25-30% matter (observed and dark) and the rest dark energy

Comment: Thank you very much, this cleared a lot up. So the issue is that you cannot preform the integral as I have stated it unless $H$ is time invariant. Observations have shown that $H = H(t)$, disproving the steady state theory's assumed "perfect cosmological principal", in which even time is isotropic and homogeneous.

The only reason it took so long for this to happen is because Hubble's observations only capture the linear nature of the expansion, due to its limited scope, as you say.

Comment: I then ask, is it evidence *besides* the distance vs. velocity relation that leads us to believe that $H$ is not constant in time? Because even more modern Hubble plots (Freedman et al.) still appear linear.

Comment: @jphollowed This relation is linear only at small scales (close objects), at larger distances the velocity is definitely not linear, there is a whole [Nobel Price](https://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/2011/press.html) awarded for that reason, and how it relates to accelerated expansion of the Universe

Comment: @caverac is right. You can see how H depends on a (and thus time in his answer). You can also see from his next to last equation that when dark energy dominates a goes like exp(Ht). Also, note that the acceleration discovery came from supernova observations at distances further away than the early Hubble linear region and that's is what the Nobel price he refers to was for.

Comment: $v=H_0 D$ is a fundamental relationship at the current epoch. $v$ and $D$ *cannot* be directly measured once you go to large distances - the "non-linearity" you are talking about comes from a naive translation of *redshift* to  a "redshift velocity", which is not what is on the left hand side of Hubble's law and is only a valid replacement at small $z$. There does not appear to be any plot of $v$ vs $D$ on the wiki article you reference, but if there were it would be a straight line. On the other hand a plot of $cz$ vs luminosity distance (which is what is usually plotted) would be curved.

Comment: There are a number of distance measures and their relationships are well known. Many prefer to use geometric measures of distance such as proper or comoving distance, because they can be interpreted from the FLRW metric and some manipulations, whereas others use more astronomical measures such as luminosity distance or angular diameter distance. If you translate right they are all fine. And it is correct that distance vs z depends on the model, and beyond small z's it's nonlinear for most. When Hubble got his equation it was more or less thought that it was a Doppler shift that related v to z

Comment: So it was common to use them interchangeably in the linearity. If you read starting at http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?bibcode=1993ApJ...403...28H&db_key=AST&page_ind=0&plate_select=NO&data_type=GIF&type=SCREEN_GIF&classic=YES you can see that Hubble's law for linearity is D vs z, and good for small cosmological distances. Linear D vs v was a construction/evolution historically, and theoretically it is exactly right, for all proper distances D, for all z's. H does change with time but so do v and D. No matter, it's an unfortunate confusion, not any basic problem

Comment: @ProfRob Could u help me https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/665094/is-hubble-graph-straight-line-or-curve

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the fact that $H$ is not constant in time. As a matter of fact, it is dominated by different quantities over cosmic time. So for instance, at very early times and after inflation

$$
H^2(a) \sim a^{-4}
$$

and right after that

$$
H^2(a) \sim a^{-3}
$$

and even more recently

$$
H^2(a) \sim a^0
$$

In all this cases $a$ is the scale factor, and

$$
\frac{H^2}{H_0^2} = \Omega_{\gamma,0}a^{-4} + \Omega_{m,0}a^{-3} + \Omega_{\Lambda,0}
$$

with

$$
H = \frac{\dot{a}}{a}
$$

Imagine for instance that the universe only contains radiation, in this case

$$
a(t)\sim t^{1/2}
$$

meaning that there's a point for which the scale of the universe goes to zero

Comment: Thank you very much, I overlooked this fact, that the integral I have posted assumes that $H$ is invariant with time. It is starting to make more sense... I haven't gotten to  the chapters on cosmological evolution yet, where the important differentials like the one you posted are introduced.